# SoundFX review site where I can upload my own SFX?

Tags: sound, effects, community

I'm looking for a place specifically to post my own SFX and receive technical feedback to improve them.

I know there's [freesound](http://freesound.org/). 
But important for me is, that there are interested people who give feedback. 
So I'm looking more for a Community... you know a place?

Comment: As it stands: I think this question is off-topic because it's asking about websites and not sound design directly. I think it could be tailored to be more useful and I've suggested an edit to that effect; I hope it helps.

Comment: You can get relevant feedback here - if you post the sound. 
The discussion will probably lead to more scientific or technical feedback here anyway.

Answer (score -1):

freesound.org is certainly capable of generating feedback - just ask for it when you post your sounds. Usually people are compliant with these sorts of requests.

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. The suggestion of asking for feedback is a pertinent and helpful step that might have been overlooked.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there's a community that has a direct focus on SFX, but you might find some helpful people at reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/edmproduction/

Those people are always looking for sounds/samples and are also providing good feedback. Might be worth a try.